# Failed to open channel for context EJBReceiverContext

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, wildfly

When I run the ejb3 remote client the service deployed in the server, `WildFly8.1.0 Final` I get the expected results. But now I am trying to benchmark this and when I run the client through the JMH `@Benchmark` method it runs fine for but after some iterations in warm up process it gives the following error.

```
Mar 04, 2015 12:29:15 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionEJBReceiver associate
INFO: EJBCLIENT000013: Successful version handshake completed for receiver context EJBReceiverContext{clientContext=org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext@13689c
56, receiver=Remoting connection EJB receiver [connection=org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConnectionPool$PooledConnection@25d8cd6c,channel=jboss.ejb,nodename=mast
er:server-three]} on channel Channel ID c1426f51 (outbound) of Remoting connection 3836a177 to /192.168.17.150:8330
Result is given by [ host: isurug ], [ Result: ONE ]
____ejb:poc_ear-1.0/poc_ejbs-1.0//DataGridServiceImpl!com.oms.ejbs.stateless.DataGridService
Mar 04, 2015 12:29:15 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.VersionReceiver handleMessage
INFO: EJBCLIENT000017: Received server version 2 and marshalling strategies [river]
Mar 04, 2015 12:29:15 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionEJBReceiver associate
INFO: EJBCLIENT000013: Successful version handshake completed for receiver context EJBReceiverContext{clientContext=org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext@538da6
b, receiver=Remoting connection EJB receiver [connection=org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConnectionPool$PooledConnection@25d8cd6c,channel=jboss.ejb,nodename=maste
r:server-three]} on channel Channel ID bed866b3 (outbound) of Remoting connection 3836a177 to /192.168.17.150:8330
Result is given by [ host: isurug ], [ Result: ONE ]
____ejb:poc_ear-1.0/poc_ejbs-1.0//DataGridServiceImpl!com.oms.ejbs.stateless.DataGridService
Mar 04, 2015 12:29:15 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionEJBReceiver$1 handleFailed
ERROR: Failed to open channel for context EJBReceiverContext{clientContext=org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext@62af85f9, receiver=Remoting connection EJB rece
iver [connection=org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConnectionPool$PooledConnection@25d8cd6c,channel=jboss.ejb,nodename=master:server-three]}
org.jboss.remoting3.ProtocolException: Too many channels open
        at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionHandler.handleOutboundChannelOpen(RemoteConnectionHandler.java:185)
        at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionHandler.open(RemoteConnectionHandler.java:318)
        at org.jboss.remoting3.ConnectionImpl.openChannel(ConnectionImpl.java:75)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConnectionPool$PooledConnection.openChannel(ConnectionPool.java:227)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionEJBReceiver.associate(RemotingConnectionEJBReceiver.java:169)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.registerEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:375)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.registerEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:327)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.setupEJBReceivers(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:159)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.getCurrent(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:115)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.getCurrent(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:47)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.getCurrent(EJBClientContext.java:271)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireCurrent(EJBClientContext.java:281)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:176)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:144)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getData(Unknown Source)
        at com.oms.client.EJBInvoker.invokeDataGridService(EJBInvoker.java:71)
        at com.test.MyBenchmark.testEjbClient(MyBenchmark.java:43)
        at com.test.generated.MyBenchmark_testEjbClient.testEjbClient_avgt_jmhLoop(MyBenchmark_testEjbClient.java:160)
        at com.test.generated.MyBenchmark_testEjbClient.testEjbClient_AverageTime(MyBenchmark_testEjbClient.java:129)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.LoopBenchmarkHandler$BenchmarkTask.call(LoopBenchmarkHandler.java:210)
        at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.LoopBenchmarkHandler$BenchmarkTask.call(LoopBenchmarkHandler.java:192)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Error says `too many channels open`, so is it like I should close the channel after a call? Or what is the cause for this and what is the solution.
Following is my remote client.

```
public class EJBInvoker {

 /**
     * Invoke Data Grid Service.
     */
    public void invokeDataGridService() {
        EJBInvoker client = null;

        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

                client = new EJBInvoker();

                String dataGridServiceJndi = "ejb:poc_ear-1.0/poc_ejbs-1.0//DataGridServiceImpl!com.oms.ejbs.stateless.DataGridService";
                DataGridService dataGridService = (DataGridService) client.lookupRemoteEJB(dataGridServiceJndi);
                String result = dataGridService.getData("1");

                System.out.println(result);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Lookup for Remote EJB
     *
     * @return {@link Object} instance.
     * @throws NamingException
     *         naming exception.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
    private Object lookupRemoteEJB(String jndiName) throws NamingException {

        Context context = null;
        try {

            Properties clientProperties = new Properties();
            clientProperties.put("remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED", "false");
            clientProperties.put("remote.connections", "default");
            clientProperties.put("remote.connection.default.port", "8330");
            clientProperties.put("remote.connection.default.host", "192.168.17.150");//192.168.16.40
            clientProperties.put("remote.connection.default.username", "admin");
            clientProperties.put("remote.connection.default.password", "1qaz2wsx@");
            clientProperties.put("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS", "false");

            EJBClientConfiguration ejbClientConfiguration = new PropertiesBasedEJBClientConfiguration(clientProperties);
            ContextSelector<EJBClientContext> contextSelector = new ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector(ejbClientConfiguration);
            EJBClientContext.setSelector(contextSelector);

            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
            context = new InitialContext(properties);

            System.out.println("____" + jndiName);

            return context.lookup(jndiName);

        } finally {
            if (context != null) {
                context.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can't create too many InitialContext. In my application, I made InitialContext as a static variable; so in the whole app, only a instance.

That solved the issue.